# How to pass params to MS Word 2003 document add-in?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, add-in, office-interop

I need to find a way to pass some strings to my word 2003 document add-in. I see many ways to do it, but none of them fits my requirements well:

1. I can write custom parameters to my word document, but when ThisDocument_Startup event handler is fired, parameters are not filled yet. I also didn't find an event, that is fired after a custom parameter is written.
2. I can use word command-line args, but I open this document via my own application and need some way to interact with opened word instance, so I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application class to do it. I didn't find a way to pass command-line args to word COM object.
3. I can use general approach to process interaction, e.g. named pipes, but IMHO that would be overkill.

Can anybody suggest a better solution? Or maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: What is your objective?  What do you want to do with the parameters.

Comment: I need to pass database connection string and some params to build a search query to db.

Comment: can you please post the code samples for passing arguments from named pipe lines. I have similar scenario where i have to pass Word addin, time and path parameters so the addin can save the document automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as nobody answered the question, I decided to use named pipes. If anyone is interested in a code sample, I can post it.

Comment: I'm interested, if you still have it available.